# Migrating ASP.NET MVC 2.0 to ASP.NET MVC 3.0: Best practices, gotchas

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, migration

We are in the process of migrating our ASP.NET MVC 2.0 web application to ASP.NET MVC 3.0. We do not intend to migrate all views to Razor and I believe it should be alright. But we use a lot of custom validation - including [Foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) which I want to get rid off as we can implement them ourselves.

So what are your experiences and things that I need to be aware of? I have read [this](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2011/02/converting-aspnet-mvc-20-application-to.html).

Answer (score 2):

My experience - **zero friction**. Including view template conversion to razor.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Did you convert your views by hand or with some third-party tool?

Comment: @Adrian Grigore by hand. At that moment - there weren't any tools. Took me whole day to rewrite around ~50 views.

Comment: I bet... I still have about 150 views to refactor. I'm still hoping Resharper will eventually offer a way to do this automatically.